# DELL Switch Configs

Tags: switch, dell

I"m not a networking expert so I was looking for advice on finding the best tool out there for automatically downloading copies of our switch config periodically and saving to a shared storage.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0% accept rate aside, I use Kiwi CatTools for just this purpose:

http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-cattools-overview/

Comment: Another vote for this - an excellent product

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 4):

While I have not used Dell networking hardware before, I am a huge ran of RANCID for backing up networking configs: http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/.

It's a simple tool that basically runs a bunch of expect scripts to log into your device, show the config and store it in version control.  While I'm not sure if Dell support is there "out of the box" a quick Google search suggested that at least one person has written some support for Dell: http://web.rickyninja.net:81/rancid/